# Is there a better way to give elements knowlege of their parents and xpath in xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree, monkeypatching, celementtree

I have the following code which works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


def get_path(self):
    parent =  ''
    path = self.tag
    sibs = self.parent.findall(self.tag)
    if len(sibs) > 1:
        path = path + '[%s]'%(sibs.index(self)+1)
    current_node = self
    while True:
        parent = current_node.parent
        if not parent:
            break
        ptag = parent.tag
        path = ptag + '/' + path
        current_node = parent
    return path

etree._Element.get_path = get_path
etree._Element.parent = None

class XmlDoc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = etree.Element('root')
        self.doc = etree.ElementTree(self.root)

    def SubElement(self, parent, tag):
        new_node = etree.SubElement(parent, tag)
        new_node.parent = parent
        return new_node

doc = XmlDoc()
a1 = doc.SubElement(doc.root, 'a')
a2 = doc.SubElement(doc.root, 'a')
b = doc.SubElement(a2, 'b')
print etree.tostring(doc.root), '\n'
print 'element:'.ljust(15), a1
print 'path:'.ljust(15), a1.get_path()
print 'parent:'.ljust(15), a1.parent, '\n'
print 'element:'.ljust(15), a2
print 'path:'.ljust(15), a2.get_path()
print 'parent:'.ljust(15), a2.parent, '\n'
print 'element:'.ljust(15), b
print 'path:'.ljust(15), b.get_path()
print 'parent:'.ljust(15), b.parent
```

Which results in this output:

```
<root><a /><a><b /></a></root> 

element:        <Element a at 87e3d6c>
path:           root/a[1]
parent:         <Element root at 87e3cec> 

element:        <Element a at 87e3fac>
path:           root/a[2]
parent:         <Element root at 87e3cec> 

element:        <Element b at 87e758c>
path:           root/a/b
parent:         <Element a at 87e3fac>
```

Now this is drastically changed from the original code, but I'm not allowed to share that.

The functions aren't too inefficient but there is a dramatic performance decrease when switching from cElementTree to ElementTree which I expected, but from my experiments it seems like monkey patching cElementTree is impossible so I had to switch.

What I need to know is whether there is either a way to add a method to cElementTree or if there is a more efficient way of doing this so I can gain some of my performance back.

Just to let you know I am thinking of as a last resort implementing selected static typing and to compile with cython, but for certain reasons I really don't want to do that.

Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT: Sorry for the wrong use of the term late binding. Sometimes my vocabulary leaves something to be desired. What I meant was "monkey patching."

EDIT: @Corley Brigman, Guy: Thank you very much for your answers which do address the question, however (and I should have stated this in the original post) I had completed this project before using lxml which is a wonderful library that made coding a breeze but due to new requirements (This needs to be implemented as an addon to a product called Splunk) which ties me to the python 2.7 interpreter shipped with Splunk and eliminates the possibility of adding third party libraries with the exception of django.

Comment: When you say "late binding", you're actually referring to monkey-patching `etree._Element` with an additional method?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for the correction. I have fixed the question because you are right.

Comment: Hmm, so you need something different. Have you tried just deriving a class from cElementTree.Element/SubElement? If you're calling `etree.parse` etc. then monkey-patching is necessary. But if you're generating the elements yourself anyways, i would think that would be straightforward. If you _are_ using parse, you might be able to get better performance by letting cElementTree parse it, and then create your own parallel tree (using its elements) with the new types + added nodes. I don't know the perf impact of that though.

Comment: My use case is a strange one I think. I am parsing a (semi-large) file (one generated by feeding a wsdl and xsd to SoapUI) and I am using that instead of parsing the wsdl and xsd myself (since I cannot rely on any third-party libraries). After that I am building my own tree based on valid attributes and chldren. This is where I need the xpath since schema.find(element.get_path())._children should give me the valid children and schema.find(element.get_path()).keys should get me the valid attributes.

Comment: Also, and sorry for all of the comments, but your new suggestion of letting cElementTree parse the large file, and creating my own custom classes sounds promissing. I will look into this and post my results.

Comment: Alright, If I had enough reputation I would upvote your answer, because by import xml.etree.cElementTree as cEtree and import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree and then parsing the large file with cEtree and monkey patching etree I have two orders of magnitude speedup. @CorleyBrigman You are awesome!!

Comment: glad to help. two orders of magnitude is pretty impressive, more than i would have guessed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *need* parents, use lxml instead - it tracks parents internally, and is still C behind the scenes so it's very fast.

However... be aware that there is a tradeoff in tracking parents, in that a given node can only have a single parent. This isn't usually a problem, however, if you do something like the following, you will get different results in cElementTree vs. lxml:

```
p = Element('x')
q = Element('y')
r = SubElement(p, 'z')
q.append(r)
```

cElementTree:

```
dump(p)
<x><z /></x>
dump(q)
<y><z /></y>
```

lxml:

```
dump(p)
<x/>
dump(q)
<y>
  <z/>
</y>
```

Since parents are tracked, a node can only have one parent, obviously. As you can see, the element `r` is *copied* to both trees in cElementTree, and *reparented/moved* in lxml.

There are probably only a small number of use cases where this matters, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I feel that it answers my question before the second edit. If anyone has any comments or other answers I would still love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use xpath, for example:

```
import lxml.html

def get_path():
    for e in doc.xpath("//b//*"):
        print e
```

should work, didn't test it though...